# embed youtube video with autoplay and no-controls

Tags: video, youtube, embed, autoplay

I want to embed a youtube video with autoplay ( the video start when you open the page ) and controls suppressed.

i tried :

I also changed the 'iframe' to 'embed', but it doesn't work.

Comment: what i tried is: <iframe  width="420" height="315"
            src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/wZZ7oFKsKzY?controls=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;cc_load_policy=1" allow="autoplay" frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

```
<video autoplay="">
            <source src="yourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the element<code>video</code>
          </video>
```

dont worry about this message "Your browser does not support the element"

i have that code in my web and its working